# Design approach: Overloading vs Switch?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, package

In regard to performance and scalability in package design, is it best to:

1. … ‘overload’ function names (letting Mathematica sort out which version to use based on patterns/conditions/tests and the way the system orders definitions)?
2. … or to construct a single function with a Switch[] (or similar command) to direct evaluation?

Mathematica’s expressiveness frequently confuses me with silly (?) issues like this.

Comment: I feel that you should add a little more detail to your questions.  It is extremely broad at this point.

Comment: Can't say I disagree with your assessment. I originally wrote much more, but realized I was rehashing basics most of us know from the manual and personal experience. I'll try and clarify if I can---but after da' bears game. :)

Comment: I also wrote a longer answer, and then realized that my examples were banal, so I left it as it is.  Enjoy the game.

Answer (score 11):

This is a broad question, but I will take this opportunity to give a broad answer...

I advocate that one should embrace the principal paradigm of a programming language, rather than trying to fight it or to write code that follows the idioms of another language.  Mathematica is built around the notion of pattern-matching so, IMHO, we should always consider pattern-matching first when trying to express ourselves.  Following that principle, I would favour definitions over `Switch`.

On the question of performance, I am becoming increasingly vexed by the growing emphasis on microbenchmarks when comparing Mathematica constructs.  While it is valuable to know the costs associated with constructs, we should heed Knuth (or was it Hoare?): "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil".  The "evil" being the loss of readability in a program that, in the interests of efficiency, uses some obscure or indirect approach to achieve an effect.  Here is my performance checklist:

1. Is performance a problem?  If not, then skip the rest of the checklist.
2. Where is the performance bottleneck?  A profiler helps here, but often the bottleneck can be found easily by inspection or a few print statements.  Then...
3. Is the algorithm inefficient?  Very frequently: is there a doubly-nested loop that could be linearized or helped out by an indexing scheme?
4. Okay, the algorithm is good so I guess it is time to microbenchmark.

I don't know if my use of Mathematica is not ambitious enough, but most of the time I don't get past step #1.  And then #3 catches most of the rest.  In Mathematica, I find I'm usually just overjoyed that I can perform some ambitious task with a small amount of code -- overall performance usually doesn't enter into the picture.

Uh-oh, I'd better put the soapbox away.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: An excellent point about using the natural paradigm. About your use of mma perhaps not being ambitious enough, it is more likely that your use of it is much too sophisticated. At least in my case, I mainly use mma for doing something along the lines of: construct very large sparse matrix, obtain eigenvalues and vectors, do something simple with them. Often, the most time-consuming parts are constructing the matrices, not solving the eigensystem. And in that case microbenchmarking (or just `Compile` to C) is one's last hope before C. For more sophisticated use, I completely agree with you.

Comment: Unless my memory fails me, I never congratulated you on 10K rep... Congratulations!

Answer (score 9):

Except for very simple cases, I prefer to use a function with multiple definitions instead of `Switch`.  The reasons for this are threefold:

1. I find it easier to read the code as long as the function is well named.
2. It's easier for the fall-through/error case to set an appropriate default and call the function again.
3. If you use a function you can use the named patterns when calculating the result.

**Edit**

Here's an example created as an example of #2 for Sjoerd:

```
createNColors[fn_, Automatic, n_] := Table[Hue[i/n], {i, n}]

createNColors[fn_, colors_List, n_] := PadRight[colors, n, colors]

createNColors[fn_, color:(Hue | RGBColor | CMYKColor | GrayLevel)[__], n_] := 
    Table[color, {n}]

createNColors[fn_, color_, n_] := (
    Message[fn::"color", HoldForm[color]]; 
    createNColors[fn, Automatic, n]
    )
```

It could be used to generate a set of *n* colors for some option.

Comment: You get +1 if you could provide a nice example of your second point  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, very instructive! The last definition, shouldn't that also be for `createNColors` instead of `createNStyle`, so that you get an appropriate handling of a call like `createNColors[fn, CIELab[1, 0.5, 0.25], 6]`?

Comment: @Sjoerd: Thanks for spotting the error.  I imperfectly renamed things at the last minute.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the performance part of your question, consider the following two examples of overloading and using `Switch[]`

```
switchFunc[a_] :=  Switch[a, _String, 5, _Integer, var, _Symbol, "string"] 

overloadFunc[a_String]  := 5;
overloadFunc[a_Integer] := var;
overloadFunc[a_Symbol]  := "string";
```

This is extremely simplified, but suffices to demonstrate the difference in performance

```
In[1]  := Timing@Nest[switchFunc, x, 1000000]
Out[1] := {3.435, "string"}

In[2]  := Timing@Nest[overloadFunc, x, 1000000]
Out[2] := {0.754, "string"}
```

However, if you intend to overload your function based on conditional tests, the performance is worse than `Switch[]`:

```
switchFunc2[a_] := Switch[a < 5, True, 6, False, 4];

overloadFunc2[a_ /; a < 5] := 6;
overloadFunc2[a_ /; a > 5] := 4;
overloadFunc2[a_] := a;

In[3]  := Timing@Nest[switchFunc2, 4, 1000000]
Out[3] := {2.63146, 4}

In[4]  := Timing@Nest[overloadFunc2, 6, 1000000]
Out[4] := {4.349, 6}
```

EDIT: The timings in this answer were made using Mathematica 8.0.1 on OS X 10.7.2. See Mr.Wizard's answer for some additional results where the above order is reversed. Nonetheless, I think it is a bad idea performance wise to do logical pattern checks on function arguments.

From a design point of view, my personal experience is that `Switch[]` and it's ilk are terrible because they are hard to read and slow. However, I also think that having the same function perform differently based on the type of argument is generally bad design and makes following your code much harder (even though it may be easier to read).

Answer (score 6):

Your question is quite vague as written, and there are different interpretations of "overloading" that would change my answer.  However, if you are talking about overloading your own functions with regard to different types (heads) and argument patterns, then by all means, take advantage of Mathematica's tightly integrated pattern matching.

---

To provide a practical example, I shall use [this solution of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166724/618728). For reference:

```
f[k_, {}, c__] := If[Plus[c] == k, {{c}}, {}]

f[k_, {x_, r___}, c___] := Join @@ (f[k, {r}, c, #] & /@ Range[0, Min[x, k - Plus[c]]])
```

If I rewrite `f` without pattern matching and call it `g`:

```
g = Function[{k, L, c},
      If[L === {},
         If[Tr@c == k, {c}, {}],
         Join @@ (g[k, Rest@L, Append[c, #]] & /@ Range[0, Min[First@L, k - Tr@c]])
      ]
    ];
```

I feel that this is less clear, and it is certainly less convenient to write.  I had to use explicit `Rest` and `First` functions, and I had to introduce `Append` as I cannot accommodate a variable number of arguments.  This also necessitates a dummy third argument in use: `{}`.

Timings show that the original form is also considerably faster:

```
f[12, {1, 5, 8, 10, 9, 9, 4, 10, 8}]; // Timing
g[12, {1, 5, 8, 10, 9, 9, 4, 10, 8}, {}]; // Timing
```

```
{0.951, Null}
```

```
{1.576, Null}
```

---

In response to Timo's answer, I feel it is of value to share my timing results, as they differ from his.  (I am using Mathematica 7 on Windows 7.)  Further, I believe he complicated the DownValues version beyond the function of the Switch version.

First, my timings of his functions as written, but using a range of values:

```
Array[switchFunc2, 1*^6]; // Timing
Array[overloadFunc2, 1*^6]; // Timing
```

```
{1.014, Null}
```

```
{0.749, Null}
```

So even as written, the DownValues function is faster for me.  But the second condition is not needed:

```
ClearAll[overloadFunc2]

overloadFunc2[a_ /; a < 5] := 6;
overloadFunc2[a_] := 4;

Array[overloadFunc2, 1*^6]; // Timing
```

```
{0.546, Null}
```

Of course, in the case of such a simple function one could also use `If`:

```
ifFunc[a_] := If[a < 5, 6, 4]

Array[ifFunc, 1*^6]; // Timing
```

```
{0.593, Null}
```

And if this is written as a pure function which Mathematica compiles inside Array:

```
ClearAll[ifFunc]
ifFunc = If[# < 5, 6, 4] &;

Array[ifFunc, 1*^6]; // Timing
```

```
{0.031, Null}
```

Comment: This reminds me of a third reason I like functions -- being able to name the patterns and reuse them later.

Comment: Nice check up on the timing! Regarding over loading too much, I'd contest that for identical functionality both of my DownValues are needed. Think about `overloadFunc2["string"]` and `switchFunc2["string"]`. Of course my expamnles are very simplistic and any real world application should be tested on its own.

Comment: @Timo I'm confused: are `*Func2` supposed to be handling strings?  How?

Comment: @Mr.W No they are not, that's the point. With your definition `overloadFunc2["string"] -> 4` whereas `switchFunc2["string"]` will not evaluate. Nitpickery, I know ;-).

Comment: Also: *expamnles* ? Seriously, when is SO getting autocorrect?

Comment: @Timo I see.  The function itself evaluates, but the `Switch` does not.  If you see typos like that in my posts, please correct them!