# Generate terms of an m-order power series in n variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Consider a situation where you have data in a list of the form

```
data = {{x1, x2, x3, ..., xn, y}, {...}, ..., {...}}
```

For example,

```
data = {{0, 2, 3, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 4}, {7, 6, 8, 3}}
```

I'd like to fit the data to a multivariate polynomial of order, say, 2.
So, the 3-variable function values are:

```
{2, 4, 3}
```

in respective points

```
{{0, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 1}, {7, 6, 8}}
```

I'd say something like

```
Fit[data, {1, x, y, z, x^2, y^2, z^2, x y , x z, y z}, {x, y, z}]
```

This is all very nice, but i may not have only 3-variate data, there may be an arbitrary number of variables, and I don't know how to programmatically generate all the linear, quadratic or even higher-order terms, to insert them as the second argument of Fit[].

For 4-variate date do second order, it would be something like:

```
{1, x1, x2, x3, x4, x1^2, x2^2, x3^2, x4^2, x1 x2, x1 x3, x1 x4, x2 x3, x2 x4, x3 x4}
```

Is there any way I can generate such a list for `n` variables, to `m`-th order?
Like terms (without coefficients) in a `m`-order power series expansion of an `n`-variable function.

Comment: Should those be `x y` instead of `xy`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
Union[Times @@@ Tuples[{1, x, y, z}, 2]]
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

While the solution of @ruebenko is perfectly correct, I'd like to mention that it will be quite slow for higher powers / larger number of variables, because of the complexity of `Tuples` and lots of duplicates for higher powers. Here is an algebraic method with a much better performance for those cases (both run-time and memory-wise):

```
List @@ Expand[(1 + x + y + z + t)^2] /. a_Integer*b_ :> b
```

Here is a comparison for large number of variables:

```
In[257]:= (res1=Union[Times@@@Tuples[{1,x,y,z,t},9]])//Short//Timing
Out[257]= {19.345,{1,t,t^2,t^3,t^4,t^5,t^6,t^7,t^8,t^9,x,<<694>>,x^2 z^7,y z^7,
      t y z^7,x y z^7,y^2 z^7,z^8,t z^8,x z^8,y z^8,z^9}}

In[259]:= (res2=List@@Expand[(1+x+y+z+t)^9]/. a_Integer*b_:>b)//Short//Timing
Out[259]= {0.016,{1,t,t^2,t^3,t^4,t^5,t^6,t^7,t^8,t^9,x,<<694>>,x^2 z^7,y z^7,
      t y z^7,x y z^7,y^2 z^7,z^8,t z^8,x z^8,y z^8,z^9}}

In[260]:= res1===res2
Out[260]= True
```

In this case, we observe a 1000x speedup, but generally the two methods just have different computational complexities. The above code is an application of a general and nice method, called Algebraic Programming. For an interesting discussion of it in the context of Mathematica, see this [Mathematica Journal paper](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i2/AlgebraicProgramming.html) by Andrzej Kozlowski.

Comment: +1, good stuff! But you know, if you FindFit with 700 vars, the 20 sec. for the vars are most likely the least of your concern ;-)

Comment: @ruebenko Sure, this is not to detract from your solution (which I upvoted) ! Conceptually, your method is more natural. This is just for the background information - and who knows, some people may need to solve the same problem for something else.

Comment: I was going to include a more efficient method in my answer, but I didn't because it [would vex WReach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8298587/618728) to optimize the fastest part of a operation.  However, I am glad you posted this, because mine used implicit loops, and I like this better.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, I agree,  we certainly should not annoy WReach. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Using @ruebenko's neat solution,

```
varsList[y_, n_?IntegerQ, k_?IntegerQ] := 
Union[Times @@@ 
 Tuples[Prepend[Table[Subscript[y, i], {i, 1, n}], 1], k]]
```

you can generate desired list via `varsList[x, 4, 2]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method that I believe is worth knowing:

```
set = {1, x, y, z};

Union @@ Outer[Times, set, set]
```